# Javascript: validate single input?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I'd like to validate a form step by step via Javascript. For example, I've like that as soon as a user fills an input box and goes to another one, a Javascript function is called. In other words, I've like to create a real-time validation.

HTML:

```
<form id="form_register" method="post" action="">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Register</legend>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label for="username">Username:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" maxlength="25" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="password">Email address:</label>
                        <input  type="text" name="email" id="email" maxlength="50"/>                    
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="password">Password:</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" maxlength="32"/> 
                    </li>
                    <li>                
                        <label for="password">Confirm Password:</label>
                        <input type="password" name="cpassword" id="cpassword" maxlength="32"/> 
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <input type="submit" value="Create Account">
            </legend>
        </fieldset>
</form>
```

I've already created the .js file and it looks like the following one.
Javascript:

```
function checkUsername(){
    //etc..
}
function checkEmail(){
    //etc..
}
function checkPassword(){
    //etc..
}
function checkConfirmPassword(){
    //etc..
}
```

How do I link the HTML page with the script?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the onblur event, as described [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp)

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" maxlength="25" onblur="checkUsername()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking to execute these functions on [the blur event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onblur) for each `input` element.  Something like this:

```
var usernameInput = document.getElementById('username');
usernameInput.onblur = checkUsername;
```

Answer (score 0):

//How do I link the HTML page with the script? Thank you.

using the script tag:

also, i am not sure why everyone is suggesting onblur, isn't onchange is better for validation purpose? why would we want to validate when the value is not changed? onblur may be required only when the validation of a field is dependant on the value of other fields.

Answer (score -1):

You could do this:

```
$('input').onblur(function() {
    if ($(this).is('[name=username]')) checkUsername()
    // etc
})
```

Comment: wish stackoverflow required people to explain why they voted something down

Comment: Well, for starters the question makes no mention of jQuery.  Additionally that combination of handler and conditional is a bit awkward.  In that case each individual `input` is going to get its own attached handler function, which internally checks the names of the inputs.  Either assign a single parent-level handler or customize individual ones, this mix of the two is kind of inefficient.

Comment: The jQuery issue, okay I'll give you that. "Kind of inefficient" - I don't buy that. Your answer assigns a listener to every input as well.

Comment: `$('input')` returns an array (in this case with 4 elements). This code then assigns an anonymous function to *each* element of the array. So there are 4 instances of this anonymous function in memory, and each instance checks against the 4 possible `input`s which could have called it.  If there are going to be 4 instances anyway, might as well tailor each one to the `input` that will be using it.